# Azure function App on secure storage container

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have an issue when we create a new function app. You have to define a storage account and we select an existing one. But this existing one is linked to a VNET.
when we click the create button, the validation is oke. but on creation time we receive an error

[image]

Is it possible to create an azure function app on a storage account that is linked to a vnet?

Comment: I would guess it's possible if the machine you're _creating_ it on is on the VNet as well. Another option would be to develop it using another storage account (or the emulator), having the App Service or Consumption Plan of the Function be in the VNet and changing the storage connection string when you deploy the Function to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently possible if you are using the consumption plan. The function application is not joined to your virtual network and so cannot access the storage account. You could use an ASE that is vNet joined to run your function, but that is very expensive. The upcoming ability to add web apps to your vNet without VPN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) may make this easier and cheaper, but again it will only be web app plan, not consumption.